# TypeError: setGameState is not a function. how can i solve it?

Tags: reactjs

MainMenu.js in reactjs

```
import React,{ useContext, useState } from "react";
import { QuizContext } from "../Helpers/Contexts";
export default function MainMenu()
{
  const {gameState, setGameState} = useState(QuizCont`enter code here`ext);

return (
<div className="Menu"> 
<button onClick={() => {setGameState("quiz");}}>Start Quiz</button> 
</div>
);
```

}

///how can i solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

`useState` returns an array, not an object:

```
const [gameState, setGameState] = useState(/*...*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

change the braces to braket (hook)
So:
const {gameState, setGameState} => const [gameState, setGameState]